# Jensen’s inequality

Tags: statistics, inequality

Prove the following by using Jensen's inequality:

$$\sum_{i=1}^m \exp(\theta^\top f_i) \geq \exp\left(\theta^\top \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i f_i - \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i \log \alpha_i\right)$$

where, $\large{\alpha_i = \frac{\exp(\hat{\theta}^\top f_i)}{\sum_{j=1}^m \exp(\hat{\theta}^\top f_j)}}$

I found that $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i = 1$ and exp is a convex function, but should we prove that $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i f_i - \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i \log \alpha_i = f_i$, then applying Jensen's inequality? or there is another way?

Comment: It looks like $f_i$ and $\theta$ are vectors but you don't make it very clear what they or $\hat\theta$ are. The term in the exponential on the right looks like a Kullback-Liebler divergence.

Comment: Yes $\theta, \hat{\theta}$, and $f_i$ are vectors
$\theta$ and $\hat{\theta}$ are just different

Comment: I think it's a straightforward case of rewriting the equation till it looks like Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Relative entropy is always non-negative ([Proof by Jensen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Information_theory)), therefore,
$$0 \geq \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i\ln\frac{\exp(\theta^{\top}f_i)}{\sum_{j = 1}^m \exp(\theta^{\top}f_j)} - \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i\ln\alpha_i$$
$$0 \geq \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i(\ln\exp(\theta^{\top}f_i) - \ln\sum_{j = 1}^m \exp(\theta^{\top}f_j)) - \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i\ln\alpha_i$$
$$\sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i\ln\sum_{j = 1}^m \exp(\theta^{\top}f_j) \geq \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i\theta^{\top}f_i - \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i\ln\alpha_i$$
$$\ln\sum_{j = 1}^m \exp(\theta^{\top}f_j) \geq \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i\theta^{\top}f_i - \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i\ln\alpha_i$$
Taking exp on both sides,
$$\sum_{j = 1}^m \exp(\theta^{\top}f_j) \geq \exp\left(\sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i\theta^{\top}f_i - \sum_{i = 1}^m \alpha_i\ln\alpha_i\right)$$

Comment: This seems to start from the result to be proven (which is indeed that relative entropy is nonnegative).

Comment: @Did Then hopefully the wikipedia link is sufficiently helpful.